# Implementing JWT on front end (understanding concept of jwt)

Tags: angular, jwt, frontend, backend

I am on part of JWT implementation, when I have token of my user, and I am implementing auth guard in Angular.
On every route change it will call isAuthenticated(),
and now I have question.
I can decode JWT token on frontend without key to get expiration, but also hacker can change his token in local storage, to increase expiration time.
If I am understanding JWT concept correctly, solution is
`a) function isAuthenticated() call API for example backend.xxx.com/isAuthenticated, if token is valid 200 - is authenticated, else 401 - isnt authenticated.`
`b) validate token with same secret that is on backend.`
Can you please tell me what is good approach to this problem? I just saw that people on tutorials/blogs decode token without validating it, so im confused that I understand it correctly

Comment: Your JWT won't prevent a malicious user from accessing any part of your angular application. Think of the token checks more as a usability feature on client-side, while all data security is handled on the server. As long as you validate the token before sending privileged information in your API, the malicious user being able to circumvent client-side AuthGuards won't matter, as they will just see an empty page. As an aside, do not store Token in localstorage. Store it in memory or in http-only cookies.

Comment: But there is case, 
User is login in for his regular account, with claim ROLE_USER.
And after that, he is changing his claims, and provide fake JWT TOKEN.
Of course, he will don't receive any confidential data but, he will be able to see layout for admin dashboard.
So should I don't care about this type of situation?

Answer (score 1):

As you may know a JWT token is composed by three parts:

Header -> Contains token type and alghoritm used

Payload -> Contains the data

Sign -> An hash calculated on the first two parts which can be computed using a passphrase.

First of all you should use the passphrase for the sign, and then use the backend to decode and validate the token each time you need. Frontend should NOT be able to decode the token, this is because the passphrase could be found in your minified js by a motivated hacker and the situation won't change.

Comment: Okey, So I should never validate token on frontend, because it can be obtained from script.
So as in discussion above, should I just don't care if someone provide fake jwt token, because he will only see empty layout, without functionality?

Comment: A fake token should result in a 401 response from backend, as the sign won't match and the backend won't validate the token. Than is up to you to decide whether to show a blank page or an error page (I like to show the error page, I care for my hackers user experience ;) )

Comment: Yes but im talking about routing.
So in your opinion In every route I should ask backend that user is authenticated FOR REAL?

Comment: I was talking about security, for routing you can just check if the token is present for user experience, you will validate it only for API calls

Comment: @korallo Basically, yes. Every API endpoint should (if it requires some kind of authentication) check that the given JWT is valid and only then report back with a 200 status (and data, possibly). Otherwise the backend returns an error code which your frontend reacts on and for example issues a "logout" in the client. This could be deletion of localStorage/cookies, redirecting to login screen, ...

Comment: because on frontend, I can just fast decode without passphrase and check that session isn't expired. If is expired, and user is hacker will not get any data, but will have access to layout/ or something.
Hope you understand

Comment: You can prevent routing checking the presence of the token and it's expiration (don't decode it, just store it in cookies and take the expiration from there).
If you don't want to disclose layout you can set a catch statement on the http interceptor resulting in a redirect to an error page when the backend return a 401 status code

Comment: But can't user modify his cookies to change expiration time? I guess he can...
As you said, backend give him 401, and In this case I can redirect him to login page and clear his token

Comment: As the frontend runs in the users browser he will always have the possibility to circumvent something. The last option, is to send an API call for every navigation button, and send the redirect from the backend, but at this point AuthGuard would be useless.

Comment: Personally, I do not use JWT tokens, but I compute a random token for every user access by using this structure -> {token: <randomuid>, user_id , expiration} in my database

Comment: AuthGuard just can call backend to Validate his Token in header, and if response is OK, then redirect him I guess

Comment: You will have problems with observables behaviour, as you should define an async method to call the API and await for the response